# fork - Can I exit from parent?

Tags: c, linux, fork, exec

I have written a code which will call `exec` as shown below. But if I call `isValid` from `main`, both child and parent process are returning and I am getting the output twice.

I want to get the out of the exec and want to check the return value in main only once. which process I need to exit inorder to make this work properly?

```
int isValid(void)
{
    int number, statval;
    int child_pid;
    child_pid = fork();
    if(child_pid == -1) { printf("Could not fork! \n"); exit( 1 ); }
    else if(child_pid == 0)
    {
        execl(...); // Child
    }
    else
    {
        // Parent
        waitpid( child_pid, &statval, WUNTRACED );
        if(WIFEXITED(statval))
        {
            if (WEXITSTATUS(statval) == 0)
                return 1;
            else
                return 0;
        }
        else
            printf("Child did not terminate with exit\n");
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    if (isValid())
    {
        printf("Valid\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Invalid\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: You can replace `WUNTRACED` with `0` unless you specifically need to handle a stopped (but not terminated) child process.

Comment: @IanAbbott: Assuming execl always succeds, I am getting once "Invalid" after that I am getting "Valid".

Comment: So don't assume `execl` always succeeds, because it looks like it is returning an error in this case. That would explain the messages you see. The child calls `execl`, which returns an error; the child then returns 0 from `isValid`; the child then prints `Invalid` in main; the child then returns from `main` and exits successfully; the parent then returns from `waitpid`, sees the child exited successfully and returns 1; the parent then prints `Valid` in `main`, returns, and exits.

Comment: when using any of the `exec...()` family of functions (none of which return if successful), always follow the `exec...()` call with `perror( "exec... failed" ); exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`

Comment: for us to debug this runtime problem, the posted code must cleanly compile.  The posted code does not cleanly compile and the parameters for the call to `execl()` are missing.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: when any system function returns an error indication, the error message should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout` and should include the reason the system thinks the error occurred.   Suggest using `perror()` most of the time (and when necessary to display some variable values, suggest using: `fprintf( stderr, ... );`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The doubled output may occur when the `execl` fails. The code above does not check the `execl` return value. Actually the `execl` returns only in case of failure so there is no need to check the returned value but it is necessary to handle error anyway.

**EDIT:**

If the `exec` fails then:

- Child's `isValid()` returns 0 at the end of the function and the main prints "Invalid"
- Parent waits for the child exit and then WIFEXITED is true because child exits and WEXITSTATUS is 0 because the child exits normally. Parent's `isValid` returns 1 and "Valid" is printed.

Comment: I think the best way to handle the `execl` error would be to optionally print an error message, and then call `exit(EXIT_FAILURE)`.

Comment: Assuming excel never fails (for simple command ls), I am getting one output "Invalid" and one output "Valid".

Comment: @NJMR: never assume that exec never fails although it is a trivial `ls` command. There could be wrong PATH set or whatever...

Comment: You were write, I was trying to execute a ping command thinking that it is stored in /bin. But ping was @ /usr/sbin/ping. Hence the exec was failing. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You probably should do some tiny things (perhaps some [usleep(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/usleep.3.html) for a few milliseconds) after the `fork` but before the `waitpid` to have some real chance to get the [waitpid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html) call succeed. Otherwise, it could happen that the other process won't be scheduled to run.
BTW, you should test the *return value* from `waitpid`, .e.g. code

```
statval = 0;
pid_t wpid = waitpid(child_pid, &statval, WUNTRACED );
if (wpid>0) {
  assert (wpid == child_pid);
  if (WIFEXITED(statval)) {
    if (WEXITSTATUS(statval) == 0)
      return 1;
```

At last, regarding the title of your question, read [job control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Job_control_%28Unix%29) wikipage, read several chapters of [*Advanced Linux Programming*](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/), and consider using [daemon(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/daemon.3.html)

Also, just after the `execl` be sure to put

```
perror("execl");
exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
```

to handle the *rare* case of `execl` failure.

Comment: I don't know why you'd need to sleep for a few millseconds.

Comment: On a uniprocessor machine, to give the kernel some opportunity to schedule the other process.

Comment: The `waitpid` call will block (unless the `WNOHANG` option is used) if the process (or any child process) being waited for hasn't terminated yet, which will give the scheduler the opportunity to schedule the other process.

Comment: You are right. I am confusing the WNOHANG with WUNTRACED

Answer (score 1):

```
    #include <sys/shm.h>
    int *tabPID;

int isValid(void)
{
    int number, statval;
    if(fork() == 0){
        tabPID[1] = getpid();
        execl(...); // Child
        return -1;
    }
    // Parent
    tabPID[0]=getpid();
    usleep(10);//as Basile Starynkevitch suggests
    waitpid(tabPID[1], &statval, WUNTRACED );
    if(WIFEXITED(statval))
    {
        if (WEXITSTATUS(statval) == 0)
            return 1;
        else
            return 0;
    }
    else
        printf("Child did not terminate with exit\n");
    return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    shmId = shmget(1234, 2*sizeof(int), IPC_CREAT|0666);
    tabPID = shmat(shmId, NULL, 0);
    if (isValid())
    {
        printf("Valid\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Invalid\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: What does this actually achieve? The use of shared memory seems over-complicated to me.

Comment: With many child proc you can easily monitor them and send signals.
@NJMR was using waitpid() for PID=0, so I think this show what was done wrong.

Comment: Unless the child processes also need to know each others' PIDs (i.e., if only the parent needs to know all the child PIDs), there is no need to store them in shared memory. I think NJMR's main problem was not dealing with `execl` returning an error. Your code above returns `-1` in that case, which would cause `main` to print `"Valid\n"` and then exit, so you would still get `"Valid\n"` printed twice - once by the child and once by the parent. The best thing to do is call `exit(1)` (or some other error status) if `execl` returns.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong. Exec should replace executed code, there so exit(1) under execl wont execut at all (only if execl fails)

Comment: Exactly. If `execl` fails, the calling process will continue running the old code.